# Predicting product of a Hofmann elimination with a cyclic amine

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, amines

What is the final product of this reaction?

[image: reaction]

Here's what I have:

[image: my solution]

Does this look correct? I'm concerned because I'm used to seeing the nitrogen removed from the product (in the cases of primary amines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With excess of methylamine, I wouldn't exclude additional methylation, yielding a trimethylanilinium iodide.

[image: alkylation of dimethylaniline]

However, the reaction should stop there since a further hydrogen abstraction from a $\beta$-position isn't possible.